# Aspect fill video as background for website - HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I aspect fill my video as background so that the full screen is always shown? Below code can fill if background width ratio is larger than the video width ratio, but cannot fill if background height ratio is larger than the video height ratio.

Any tips for the aspect fill?

Html

```
<video autoplay muted loop playsinline class="myVideo" id="backgroundVideo">
    <source src="assets/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

css

```
.myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

Comment: Please explain "aspect fill automation".

Comment: @WaisKamal like aspectFill from Xcode https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvml/image_attributes/aspectfill

Comment: I am not familiar with XCode. Please describe the desired result.

Comment: @WaisKamal the video can fills the entire screen with same aspect ratio

Comment: you need `max-width:100vw` and `max-height:100vh`.

Comment: Use `object-fit`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: @WaisKamal this would have some spaces left if the screen size is different with the video size

Comment: @Terry works perfect by adding ```width: 100%; height: 100%;```. Thanks